# Подключение кода С++ к С#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll

У меня есть несколько классов, с разнообразными методами взаимодействия со структурами данных, несколько простых функций. Все написано на языке С++.
У меня есть готовый интерфейс на С#, а так же представление как использовать методы моих классов для получения нужного результата.
Все происходит в MVS 13 года.

Но вот вопрос. Как соединить C# проект с С++ кодом?

Я знаю. Было уже много постов здесь(и не только здесь) на эту тему, я их читал. Но внятного ответа не получил. Как и результата экспериментов после прочтения.

Я пытался создать CLR DLL Библиотеку классов, подключить ее к C# через using %название_dll%. Сначала у меня не видело пространство имен моей библиотеки, потом после добавления public к каждой структуре и классу все подключилось, но не было видно простых функций, а все остальное выступало лишь в виде структур и при попытки вызова метода через %имя_пространства%.%имя_класса%.%имя метода% или же %имя_класса%.%имя метода% ничего не происходило, писало что такие вещи не были определены. И когда я смотрел обозреватель решений моей библиотеки там действительно ничего не было.

Пытался создать через win32 библиотеку, но при подключении выдавалось что это не COM-решения или что-то в этом духе. Читал потом нужно динамически подключать, но так и не разобрался с этим, полагая что существует метод легче и правильнее в моем случае(полагаю, что неправильно я полагал).

Так же читал что-то про managed c++ и создание простого dll файла, который C# может видеть спокойно. Но что за формат c++ такой я тоже не знаю(возможно CLR как раз).

В общем вопрос таков. Каким способом мне классы и фукнции C++ соединить с C#, что бы я мог использовать методы и функции в обработчиках в проекте C#.

Спасибо.

Comment: В принципе все перечисленные способы верны. Показывай упрощённый пример кода C++ (структура с парой полей, которую надо передавать, класс с парой простых методов, которые нужно вызывать).

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать C++/CLI (то, что у вас называется CLR DLL), вы должны чётко понимать разницу между нативным и .NET-классом. Из .NET вы можете пользоваться только .NET-классами. Использовать нативные классы напрямую из .NET-кода не получится.